# Riemann Sum. Check proof.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, riemann-sum

> Let $f:[a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\displaystyle\sum(f; P^{\ast})$ a Riemann sum. Prove that, if $\displaystyle \lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum(f; P^{\ast}) = L$, then $f$ is a limited function

$\textbf{My idea:}$ Suppose that $f$ is unlimited, so $f$ is unlimited in a partition interval $[t_{s-1}, t_{s}]$ of $P = \lbrace t_{0}, ..., t_{n} \rbrace$. Thus, for all $A > 0$ theres exist a $c_{s} \in [t_{s-1}, t_{s}]$ such that
$$|f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1})| > \Bigg|\sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\Bigg| + A.$$
Therefore
$$\Bigg|\sum(f;P^{\ast})\Bigg| = \Bigg|f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1}) + \sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\Bigg| > A.$$
So, $\displaystyle \lim_{|P|\to 0}\sum(f; P^{\ast})$ doesn't exist.

Is this a correct idea?

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer corresponds to the [original version](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2656020/1) of the question.

The second last inequality should be
$$|f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1})| > \Bigg|\sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\Bigg| \color{red}{+A},$$
so that
\begin{align}
\left|\sum(f;P^{\ast})\right| &= \Bigg|f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1}) + \sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\Bigg| \\
&\ge \left||f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1})| - \Bigg|\sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\Bigg|\right| \\
&= |f(c_{s})(t_{s} - t_{s-1})| - \left|\sum\limits_{k=1, k\neq s}^{n}f(c_{k})(t_{k} - t_{k-1})\right|
 > A
\end{align}
for an arbitrarily large $A>0$.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen it.